# Unity 3D game - trouble with simple PNGs of circles

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, 3d, geometry, png

We are having a game developed by a Unity programmer.

There seems to be an issue with imported PNG files we have supplied. Its a simple solid circle, and I have left some transparent space around it. Its very big, 150dpi, and then is scaled to the rightsize by the game code.

Sometimes though, these circles appear to have a flat edge, like theres a row of pixels missing, and nothing we try seems to rectify this.

Looking for ideas of things to try. Is it to do with snapping? Scaling issues for some reason? Should it be a multiple of 256 or anything like that.

Anything you can suggest would be great
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be issues with you you are exporting the PNG or with how you are importing it into Unity. Without knowing the size or how exactly you are using the image I can only speak to general best practices.

Unity's scaling algorithms are good but not perfect. If you are using the image as a texture (ie. on geometry in the scene) your texture needs to be sizes to a power of two (2px,4px,8px,16px,32px,64px,128px,256px,512px) but it does not need to be square so 256x512px is fine. If your image dimensions are not powers of two I believe unity will squash the image which can cause visual artifacts.

If you are using the image on a GUI they can be arbitrarily sized.

The first thing to look at is the import settings. Assuming you have already dragged the texture into Unity, select the the texture in the project pane and look at the options in the inspector.

**Texture type:** Unity will handle an image differently depending on its target use so make sure you have the type set correctly.

**Filter Mode:** your choice of filter mode is largely dependent on the content of the image. THe easiest way to see which one you want is to just try them all.

Hope some ome of this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the import settings of the images in the project folder, check out the dimension-settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes images can be scaled to a size that doesn't fit perfectly into pixels. For example the image is scaled so that it is 100.2 pixels wide or is positioned at 50.3,41.2 pixels from the upper left. This can lead to ugly aliasing artifacts, which sounds like what you're seeing. Also, the mipmapping of a large texture to a smaller size can create artifacts (sometimes it hides the artifacts, so damned if you do...).

Try turning off mipmapping, and making sure the size and position of the images are whole numbers.  There are 2D frameworks available for Unity to make this easier to do (NGUI has a "make pixel perfect" button, I assume other have something similar).  Also, delivering artwork that is close to the screen's resolution can help.